# Using Ember data's find in route setupController in Ember 1.0.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

*[I'm on Ember 1.0.0 - Ember.data 0.13]*

In a nested route I'm using the `setupController` hook in order to load a list of templates which I use as selection list for my model, a `Offer` object:

```
controller.set('offerTemplates', App.OfferTemplate.find());
```

Complete code:

```
App.OfferEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.modelFor("offer");
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
        controller.set('offerTemplates', App.OfferTemplate.find());
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render('offer-edit-title', { into: 'application', outlet: 'page-title', controller: 'offerEdit' });
        this.render('offer-edit', { into: 'application', controller: "offerEdit" }); //
    }
});

App.OfferEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    offerTemplates: [],
    ...
)};
```

This used to work until Ember 1 RC 7, but doesn't in 1.0.0. The main content of the `Offer` (model) is correctly rendered, but the template list bound to the controller's `offerTemplates` property (array) is not rendered on loading the page (browser page refresh).

If I switch page and back to the route, all is rendered correctly.

Any hint?

Comment: Oops, that's just a copy paste mistake I made copying from two similar files. It's the OfferEditController. Sorry! I've updated the post.

Comment: which version of Ember Data are you using? Beta 1?

Comment: @colymba No still on Ember.data 0.13

Comment: Have you checked wether the property is actually populated? Try `App.__container__.lookup("controller:offerEdit").get("offerTemplates.length")`

Comment: @mavilein yes, it's fetched from the server's API and populated. Result: 12 (which is the correct number of offerTemplates)

Comment: Can you show the template? There must be a minor problem in the template.

Comment: Oops, I found the problem. Will update post / write answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the template which doesn't use the `offerTemplates` array but a **computed property** `offerTemplatesByGuestUserLanguage`:

```
{{#each offerTemplate in offerTemplatesByGuestUserLanguage}}
    ...
{{/each}}
```

I forgot the second to add the second property `content.guestUser.language` in the computed property of the controller:

```
offerTemplatesByGuestUserLanguage: function() {
    var templates = this.get("offerTemplates"),
        guestUserLanguageCode = this.get("content.guestUser.language.code");

    return templates.filter(function (item) {
        return item.get("language.code") === guestUserLanguageCode;
    });
}.property('offerTemplates.@each', 'content.guestUser.language')
```

I wonder why it even worked in RC.7.

Comment: Maybe there have been minor timing changes in Ember. In RC7 the property was conincidentally computed at the right time, i guess.

Comment: @mavilein yes that could be the explanation. Thanks for your help!